# Access Validation of Checkboxes

Tags: validation, ms-access

I have an access database that in one of the table I have two fields with yes/no boxes (set to True/False).

The used need not check either one, but if [BoxA] is true, then [BoxB] must be false.  I tried to do this validation is with Xor, but then one of them must be checke.

I'm using Access 2010, but the database is in format 2002-2003 (mdb) to maintain compatibility with another application.

Can someone point me in the right direction to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate what version of Access you are using.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From table design view, set a Validation Rule in the table's property sheet.

[image: table Validation Rulle]

For clarity, this is the property from that image:

```vb
([BoxA] = False And [BoxB] = False) Or ([BoxA] = Not [BoxB])
```

The db engine will enforce the requirement that only one of those two fields can be `True` (checked), or both can be `False` (unchecked).

Comment: Rats. You edited your answer just before I was about to call you on it. :)

Comment: Spectacular - That works perfectly.  If I could only reward you for speed!